Segmented longtable(longtblr) across multiple columns
I am trying to create a checklist.
As the rows of the checklist aren't to wide it would be nice to split the page into two columns.
However longtable does not support 2 Column mode and longtblr works but breaks after page end and continues on the next page instead of the next column. There is a way for longtable to work in two column mode however it still does not properly break.
I have attached a minimal non working example.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    
\begin{longtblr}{
    colspec = {Q[c!,white]Q[c!,white]Q[l,white]},
    hlines, vlines,
    }
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
    Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
    Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
    Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}

If that works, it would be great to create blocks of rows that may never be broken but allow for page breaks before and after.

longtblr works fine in standard two-column mode, so perhaps you can simply use that.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn    
\begin{longtblr}{
    colspec = {Q[c!,white]Q[c!,white]Q[l,white]},
    hlines, vlines,
  }
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
  Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
  Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
\end{longtblr}

\onecolumn
\kant[1]
\end{document}


That worked perfectly thank you. I wonder how I did not find that solution.

@N0W0RK Probably because you'd been staring at your own code for too long ;).

The late hour probably also didn't help.

@N0W0RK ;) Also, it doesn't work with longtable.
